# Expo Go crashes after trying to call a function within the Reanimated Gesture Handler

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I am using react-native-animated library for the gesture handling.

```
const pan = Gesture.Pan()
      .onChange((e)=>{
        offSetX.value = e.translationX
        
      })
      .onEnd((e)=>{
        if (e.translationX>0){
          screenStore.handleSwipeRight(); //here
        }else if(e.translationX<0){
          screenStore.handleSwipeLeft(); //here
        }
      })
```

When either of the two marked functions are called it crashes my Expo Go simulation.
In fact no function works.

I have specific logic I'd wish to call after certain gesture ends. Any ideas how I should proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [runOnJS](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/2.x/api/miscellaneous/runOnJS/)

```
    import { runOnJS } from "react-native-reanimated";

    const pan = Gesture.Pan()
      .onChange((e) => {
        offSetX.value = e.translationX
      })
      .onEnd((e) => {
        if (e.translationX > 0) {
          runOnJS(screenStore.handleSwipeRight)(); // <----
        } else if(e.translationX < 0) {
          runOnJS(screenStore.handleSwipeLeft)(); // <----
        }
      })
```